# possibleTypes doesn't work with subfields of typePolicies

Tags: apollo-client, vue-apollo

For a bigger project I tried to use the InMemoryCache config of Apollo to write something like a default mergefunction. The possibleTypes inheritance looks like it could help, but it seems to not work with subfields. My queries are all saved below the ROOT_QUERY, so I have to use the subfields instead of the fields directly. Grateful for any help!

My current code looks like this, but doesn't work:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  possibleTypes: {
    queryName: ['apple', 'banana'],
  },
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        queryName: {
          merge: false,
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Which should be the same as this code, that works:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        apple: {
          merge: false,
        },
        banana: {
          merge: false,
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`possibleTypes` is as the name implies for inheritance of type names - it doesn't work for fields, which are a competely different concept.

Is there anything in the documentation that indicates that this might work?

Comment: Ah okay, I thought thats maybe just an array of typenames which would have been okay for my code. The documentation only has one basic example, so I  just hoped I could find a workaround for setting a default for all fields with that.

Comment: But you are not using them as type names. "type name" means "the name of a GraphQL type". Fields are not types.